# Encountered Bus Error while trying to run code in CUDA

Tags: laptop, power-supply, gpu, c, cuda

[This](https://github.com/zchee/cuda-sample/blob/master/0_Simple/vectorAdd/vectorAdd.cu) was the code that I was trying to run on my computer when I encountered this error.

```
./l
[Vector addition of 10 elements]
Bus error (core dumped)
```

I tried this

```
>>>> nvcc -o l vectorAdd.cu -v 
#$ _SPACE_= 
#$ _CUDART_=cudart
#$ _HERE_=/usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/bin
#$ _THERE_=/usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/bin
#$ _TARGET_SIZE_=
#$ _TARGET_DIR_=
#$ _TARGET_SIZE_=64
#$ NVVMIR_LIBRARY_DIR=/usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/libdevice
#$ PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/bin:/home/anshuman/Downloads/bin:/home/anshuman/anaconda3/bin:/usr/class/cs143/cool/bin:~/get-shit-done/:/home/anshuman/.local/bin:/home/anshuman/bin:/usr/local/cuda-10.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/anshuman/Documents/PCAP/.openmpi/bin:/home/anshuman/Documents/PCAP/bin:/usr/local/m4/bin/:/home/anshuman/bin:/usr/local/cuda-10.1/bin:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcublas.so.10:/usr/local/bin/
#$ LIBRARIES=  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/stubs
#$ gcc -std=c++14 -D__CUDA_ARCH__=300 -E -x c++  -DCUDA_DOUBLE_MATH_FUNCTIONS -D__CUDACC__ -D__NVCC__  -D"__CUDACC_VER_BUILD__=85" -D"__CUDACC_VER_MINOR__=1" -D"__CUDACC_VER_MAJOR__=9" -include "cuda_runtime.h" -m64 "vectorAdd.cu" > "/tmp/tmpxft_00000213_00000000-8_vectorAdd.cpp1.ii" 
#$ cicc --c++14 --gnu_version=70300 --allow_managed  -arch compute_30 -m64 -ftz=0 -prec_div=1 -prec_sqrt=1 -fmad=1 --include_file_name "tmpxft_00000213_00000000-2_vectorAdd.fatbin.c" -tused -nvvmir-library "/usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/libdevice/libdevice.10.bc" --gen_module_id_file --module_id_file_name "/tmp/tmpxft_00000213_00000000-3_vectorAdd.module_id" --orig_src_file_name "vectorAdd.cu" --gen_c_file_name "/tmp/tmpxft_00000213_00000000-5_vectorAdd.cudafe1.c" --stub_file_name "/tmp/tmpxft_00000213_00000000-5_vectorAdd.cudafe1.stub.c" --gen_device_file_name "/tmp/tmpxft_00000213_00000000-5_vectorAdd.cudafe1.gpu"  "/tmp/tmpxft_00000213_00000000-8_vectorAdd.cpp1.ii" -o "/tmp/tmpxft_00000213_00000000-5_vectorAdd.ptx"
#$ ptxas -arch=sm_30 -m64 "/tmp/tmpxft_00000213_00000000-5_vectorAdd.ptx"  -o "/tmp/tmpxft_00000213_00000000-9_vectorAdd.sm_30.cubin" 
#$ fatbinary --create="/tmp/tmpxft_00000213_00000000-2_vectorAdd.fatbin" -64 --cmdline="" "--image=profile=sm_30,file=/tmp/tmpxft_00000213_00000000-9_vectorAdd.sm_30.cubin" "--image=profile=compute_30,file=/tmp/tmpxft_00000213_00000000-5_vectorAdd.ptx" --embedded-fatbin="/tmp/tmpxft_00000213_00000000-2_vectorAdd.fatbin.c" --cuda
#$ rm /tmp/tmpxft_00000213_00000000-2_vectorAdd.fatbin
#$ gcc -std=c++14 -E -x c++ -D__CUDACC__ -D__NVCC__  -D"__CUDACC_VER_BUILD__=85" -D"__CUDACC_VER_MINOR__=1" -D"__CUDACC_VER_MAJOR__=9" -include "cuda_runtime.h" -m64 "vectorAdd.cu" > "/tmp/tmpxft_00000213_00000000-4_vectorAdd.cpp4.ii" 
#$ cudafe++ --c++14 --gnu_version=70300 --allow_managed --m64 --parse_templates --gen_c_file_name "/tmp/tmpxft_00000213_00000000-5_vectorAdd.cudafe1.cpp" --stub_file_name "tmpxft_00000213_00000000-5_vectorAdd.cudafe1.stub.c" --module_id_file_name "/tmp/tmpxft_00000213_00000000-3_vectorAdd.module_id" "/tmp/tmpxft_00000213_00000000-4_vectorAdd.cpp4.ii" 
#$ gcc -std=c++14 -D__CUDA_ARCH__=300 -c -x c++  -DCUDA_DOUBLE_MATH_FUNCTIONS -m64 -o "/tmp/tmpxft_00000213_00000000-10_vectorAdd.o" "/tmp/tmpxft_00000213_00000000-5_vectorAdd.cudafe1.cpp" 
#$ nvlink --arch=sm_30 --register-link-binaries="/tmp/tmpxft_00000213_00000000-6_l_dlink.reg.c"  -m64   -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/stubs -cpu-arch=X86_64 "/tmp/tmpxft_00000213_00000000-10_vectorAdd.o"  -o "/tmp/tmpxft_00000213_00000000-11_l_dlink.sm_30.cubin"
#$ fatbinary --create="/tmp/tmpxft_00000213_00000000-7_l_dlink.fatbin" -64 --cmdline="" -link "--image=profile=sm_30,file=/tmp/tmpxft_00000213_00000000-11_l_dlink.sm_30.cubin" --embedded-fatbin="/tmp/tmpxft_00000213_00000000-7_l_dlink.fatbin.c" 
#$ rm /tmp/tmpxft_00000213_00000000-7_l_dlink.fatbin
#$ gcc -std=c++14 -c -x c++ -DFATBINFILE="\"/tmp/tmpxft_00000213_00000000-7_l_dlink.fatbin.c\"" -DREGISTERLINKBINARYFILE="\"/tmp/tmpxft_00000213_00000000-6_l_dlink.reg.c\"" -I. -D__NV_EXTRA_INITIALIZATION= -D__NV_EXTRA_FINALIZATION=  -D"__CUDACC_VER_BUILD__=85" -

D"__CUDACC_VER_MINOR__=1" -D"__CUDACC_VER_MAJOR__=9" -m64 -o "/tmp/tmpxft_00000213_00000000-12_l_dlink.o" "/usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/bin/crt/link.stub" 
#$ g++ -m64 -o "l" -std=c++14 -Wl,--start-group "/tmp/tmpxft_00000213_00000000-12_l_dlink.o" "/tmp/tmpxft_00000213_00000000-10_vectorAdd.o"   -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/stubs -lcudadevrt  -lcudart_static  -lrt -lpthread  -ldl  -Wl,--end-group
```

However, I am not really sure what is going wrong here. Can someone help.

​

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Nov__3_21:07:56_CDT_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.1, V9.1.85
```

​

```
 nvidia-smi
Sat Apr  6 15:58:15 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.116                Driver Version: 390.116                   |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce 940MX       Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   51C    P5    N/A /  N/A |    842MiB /  4046MiB |     12%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1341      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           293MiB |
|    0      1708      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         311MiB |
|    0      2282      G   ...uest-channel-token=10764068675564210353   181MiB |
|    0     29177      G   ...uest-channel-token=10528584851110459654    52MiB |
```

My GPU is 940MX,  I am sure the code is not wrong as I have run this on another machine where it executed perfectly fine. Plus, it is from the CUDA's official code repository. Finding stuff online has been really unfruitful as most of it relates to Python and Tensorflow, which I have not been using in this instance. 
However, I had another suggestion from Reddit saying that :

> It's quite likely your power supply isn't enough. I was running into this issue when porting some torch deep learning models over to industrial computers. The power supplies on the machines we used to build and test the models were significantly more powerful than the ones in the deployment boxes, and I ended up seeing this error quite a bit.

Now I am not really sure about what that means. I have an HP Pavilion laptop for which I have been using the original charger and an original battery, (which was replaced last November due to a defect in the original one).
The issue seems to have begun  only after I tried upgrading to CUDA 10.0
[unsucessfully]
Also, if anyone has suggestions for cloud-based GPU's that I can temporarily use, as I need this for a project. I was thinking AWS but that seems way too expensive.

Comment: I have seen several reports about problems with CUDA 10.0. The solution was always to use an earlier version.

Comment: It is CUDA 9.1 mate.

Comment: Better clarify in your post what you did use, do use, and what changed and why.

Comment: Sorry, I had tried upgrading to 10.0 but the thing never installs, but that is another problem for another day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say that the problem only appeared after the botched installation of
CUDA 10.0, this might mean that this installation was not fully undone,
so that you now have a non-working mixture of the two versions.

It might be better to uninstall all NVIDIA products except the video driver,
clean out all folders, then reinstall CUDA 9.1.
The
[documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#runfile-uninstallation)
lists this command:

```
sudo /usr/local/cuda-<version>/bin/cuda-uninstaller
```

On Windows I would have advised using an uninstaller such as
[Revo Uninstaller freeware](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html)
for getting all the left-over bits and pieces, but on Linux
you might need to search for the "cuda" sub-string on the disk
to get these left-overs.

Comment: I can't find anything related to CUDA 10.0 and I ran this command dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia to get https://pastebin.com/L43ZZK4R

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable about these files, but I would do a clean uninstall of everything NVIDIA and reinstall as the solution. Note that the left-overs may be config files that are created or modified by the installation, but not included in it.

Comment: I will try that, but for now, I might have to just use Colab.

Answer (score 0):

What harrymc said was correct and I followed the steps in this [link](https://computervisionpoints.com/2018/12/17/installation-of-nvidia-driver-and-cuda-10-0-in-ubuntu-16-04/) exactly to fix this issue. I figured that perhaps the old file for CUDA 10.0 was perhaps corrupt and I purged everything including the 9.0 and 10.0, then redid everything.